# Change DPI setting in Windows 8.1 for the Logon Screen

Tags: login, windows-8.1, dpi

## How can the DPI setting be changed for the Logon Screen in Windows 8.1?

Microsoft has added per-user DPI settings. But this means that there is no adjustable DPI setting for the Lock/Logon screen.

You can change the DPI setting to be the same across all displays and this *does* affect the icons and font on the lock/logon screen. However, it *does not* affect any app/program that can run on the lock/logon screen.

Ex.
I use a 44" flat screen TV for my monitor on my desktop. Big enough for me to sit in my recliner and use my computer. I use the on-screen keyboard most of the time.  (I don't want to keep a keyboard next to me.)

The problem is that with the new DPI setup the on-screen keyboard takes up nearly half the screen, which is too big.

I tried looking through the registry to see if I could find a setting for it. In the key `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop`  there is a string value named `LogicalDPIOverride` with a value of `-1`. I have a feeling this is where I can fix the issue. I tried changing the value to 0 and to 1 with no change in the result. Instead I noticed that after logging out and back in the -1 value was back in the registry.

How can I change this default DPI? Can I use the `LogPixels` string that worked for DPI in Windows 7?

Here are two Screen shots, one of the Lock Screen and one of the Logon Screen:

[image: lock screen screenshot]

[image: logon screen screenshot]

Comment: The on screen keyboard is exactly the same size in both of these screenshots. So there's no problem demonstrated here!

Comment: I guess the keyboard should be smaller?  It takes up half the screen and it should be a different size.

Comment: The screens are to show you the auto scaling when I'm logging in. I was hoping to find a way to turn off auto scaling for the logon desktop. It isn't affected by the settings from accounts. The new per-user settings Microsoft has implemented make it so no account can change logon.

Comment: Also it says right in my question it is too big.

Answer (score 0):

In order for LogicalDPIOverride to work you need to set value larger than 1.

For example on Macs with retina screen you'd need to set it to 2 - which will result in 200% UI scaling.